# How do I use a custom script in Google Spreadsheets for conditional formatting?

Tags: google-sheets

Google Scripts use Javascript, and I haven't gotten around to learning Javascript yet, so I kept it really simple. Here is an example spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19yrUahvBt8GQMMZnykJ9i9xAoeVfMkw681HxOIj2_4I/edit?usp=sharing

The column on the left is a fixed list of terms. The column on the right is a list of manually entered terms by the user. If the user enters one of the terms on the left into one of the cells on the right, then the cell on the right should turn green (not case sensitive). So in this example, I want B4 and B5 to turn green.

Here is my script:

```
function Script1(singlecell, valuesy) {

  for(var y = 0; y < valuesy.length; y++) {

    var tempx = String(singlecell).toLowerCase().trim();
    var tempy = String(valuesy[y]).toLowerCase().trim();

    if((tempx === tempy)&&(!((tempx.length===0)||(tempy.length===0)))) {

      return true;
    }

  }

  return false;  
}
```

Here are both my attempts to get some sort of conditional formatting using the script:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3I5y.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMZxw.png

Neither of these work.

The reason I want this to work is because I'm using something similar in my budget spreadsheet.

I know there are more complicated methods where the script grabs the actual spreadsheet and changes the format of the cells itself. I would rather not use that method if I can help it.

EDIT: the "duplicate" question doesn't mention custom scripts at all. So while the solution may be the same (use "match" or "countif"), the question is not the same. Because the actual answer to my question is: "you can't use conditional formatting with custom scripts." (Also the first question was horrible and didn't include any code attempts or spreadsheets, so I'd rather mine not get deleted)

Comment: @pnuts my question isn't exactly the same. I added an edit because the website told me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create a custom function. You just need to use a different formula in your Conditional Formatting instead:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1, $A$2:$A, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Well that's interesting. I have a few questions about this. 1) is $A$2:$A referencing "the entire column A, starting at A2"? If so, I should probably start using that instead of my current method (I would use something like $A$2:$A$400). 2) the documentation doesn't mention that MATCH is not case sensitive. I just wanted to verify that I can rely on this behavior.

Comment: @user1790047 Yes to both, and you can easily check number 2 with dummy data.

Comment: yeah I tried dummy data. I'm just used to Java, which is kind of like... The documentation king. It's going to be annoying not being able to rely on documentation as I grow my spreadsheet skills in the future, but I guess it is what it is. I marked your answer as the "correct answer" (although I'd still like to know why my script didn't work - scripts are slow and bog down spreadsheets, so your answer is a better solution anyway). I can't believe I can do all this complicated spreadsheet stuff, but I didn't even know how to reference part of an entire column... lol

Comment: I also noticed your original message said it would never work with a script if I didn't grab the entire spreadsheet. I did actually find a solution using the script, but it was awful (you would have to dedicate an entire column to the script, and then use the returned values in that column for the conditional formatting... Not a nice solution lol)

Comment: @user1790047 I'm not aware of documentation that states this, but custom functions simply don't work as custom formulas for conditional formatting. At least, I haven't been able to make them work. In my original answer, I didn't realize that you were attempting to use a custom function. In typical scripts, you need to get the spreadsheet before you can get any value using something like `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` (not needed for custom functions, since they're passed the values directly and require no user permissions).